# Cannot change Excel language to a language different from Windows language?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, language

I have a Microsoft Office Home and Business 2019 account and I want to set the Excel language to French while keeping the Windows language as English.

I found out that MS Office offers a UI where one can select Editing language, Display language and Help language individually but that doesn't seem to be in my case. I have the following UI:

[image]

Here it says that the Office display language follows the preferred language. So, if my system language is English then Excel is also in English and if my system language is French then Excel is also in French. Is there any way to set English as system language and French as Excel language?

Answer (score 0):

The interface of your Office Languae is different with mine.

How did you install this Office?

I suggest you reinstall Office from your Services & Subscription, click Install and set English.

[image]

Besides, you may also try to install Office Home and Business 2019 via ODT and configuration file (.xml file).

The .xml file you may refer to the following. But please note, you could not set a different language for one Office application independently.

```
<Configuration>
  <Add OfficeClientEdition="64" >
    <Product ID="HomeBusiness2019Retail" >
      <Language ID="en-us" />
    </Product>
  </Add> 
</Configuration>
```

The steps of this installation, please refer to "[How to: Installing Office 2019 Home & Business with ODT](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/160576-installing-office-2019-home-business-with-odt)".

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look as per your suggestion.

Comment: @NavjotSingh You are welcome, hope the information could help you.